# Apache 2.4 multiple applications on separate IPs under single domain

Tags: apache, vhosts

I am a little lost on how to achieve the following...

I have a single domain name which is running a CMS @ www.mywebsite.com

If a specific URL is given apache calls the other VM (different IPv4) running a shop. www.mywebsite.com/store

I've trawled through apache vhosts but nothing seemingly covers the above scenario if its even possible ...https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to post some of your vhost configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could do this with mod_proxy.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com

    ProxyPass /store/ http://store.local/
    ProxyPassReverse /store/ http://store.local/
</VirtualHost>
```

You could use the IP address, server hostname or whatever in the proxy directives - store.local is just an example.

The [mod_proxy documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) is extensive.